# Rails 5 API - redirect to different controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 API app I've got functionality where, based on webhook information, some actions should be invoked by another controller (or should do exactly the same). Example below:

`controllers/api/v1/webhooks_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::WebhooksController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'user', password: 'pass'

  def create
    action_name = params[:webhook][:queryResult][:intent][:displayName]

    action_name == 'get-calendar' ? get_calendar_method : get_room_method
    status: :ok
  end
```

The thing is `get_calendar_method` represents all code from different endpoint (does exactly the same):

`controllers/api/v1/calendar/user_calendar.rb`

```
  def index
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = Rails.configuration.gcp_name
    service.authorization = credentials

    @entries = ::Calendar::GetEvents.call(service, **get_events_date)
  end
```

How should I deal with such situation? Should I redirect user to this `user_calendar#create` controller? If yes how to do so?

Comment: something like `redirect_to create_user_calendar_path` should get you there.  Use `rake routes` to get the correct `path` variable

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a service object. Redirection, IMO, is not the way to go.

Comment: @jvillian so what you suggest is to move all the logic of the code from the controller to the service and use it in two places, am I right?

Comment: All of the common code that sets up and calls the external API, yes.